# .Net, Azure routes other than index are not working, how do I fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

Part of my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/dragon")]
    public IActionResult Dragon()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        if(HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Dachi>("Dachi") == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Dachi", new Dachi());
        }
        Dachi dachi = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Dachi>("Dachi");
        ViewBag.Fullness = dachi.fullness;
        ViewBag.Happiness = dachi.happiness;
        ViewBag.Meal = dachi.meal;
        ViewBag.Energy = dachi.energy;
        return View();
    }
```

When I go to "myurl.azurewebsites.net/dragon"
It should start this simple dragon game.

However, I get a message that it is unable to handle its request.
My "" route (the Index) works fine.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
        </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\logs\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Why is my route other than Index not showing up???
Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use '\' on your route. Remove the same and it should work. To learn about routes - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#routes

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you mean use "dragon" instead of "/dragon"? I tried it, and it still doesn't work. Can you think of any other suggestion?

Comment: yes. I meant that. un comment code within your `Dragon` route method and check if it works. If it does nt hit any breakpoint within that method. you got show us how you ahve configured your routes on routes.cs page to know more

Comment: I don't have routes.cs file. My routes are specified in the controller.

Comment: Have you defined any default route anywhere that might override this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it turns out that I had a typo in my namespace... lol